# Frequency/contingency table across two groups of dummy variables

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a Dataframe of survey results; one column per question, one row per respondent. Q1 and Q2 are multiple choice questions and are coded in dummy variable style, one column per option. E.g.:

```
d=pd.DataFrame({
    'Q1a':[0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],
    'Q1b':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'Q1c':[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
    'Q1d':[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0],
    'Q2a':[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    'Q2b':[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
    'Q2c':[1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]
})

print d
   Q1a  Q1b  Q1c  Q1d  Q2a  Q2b  Q2c
0    0    1    1    0    1    0    1
1    0    1    0    1    1    1    0
2    0    1    0    1    1    1    1
3    1    1    0    0    0    0    1
4    1    1    0    1    0    0    1
5    0    1    1    1    0    1    1
6    1    1    1    0    0    1    0
7    1    1    0    0    0    0    1
```

So this example has 8 respondents, Q1 has 4 options and Q2 has 3.

I need a frequency table showing the number (or %) of respondents that ticked 'yes' for each pair combination in Q1 and Q2:

```
    Q2a Q2b Q2c
Q1a 0   1   3
Q1b 3   4   6
Q1c 1   2   2
Q1d 2   3   3
```

So 6 respondents said yes to both Q1b and Q2c.

Conceptually, a command like

```
import pandas as pd
pd.value_counts(
    rows    = (d['Q1a'],d['Q1b'],d['Q1c'],d['Q1d']),
    columns = (d['Q2a'],d['Q2b'],d['Q2c'])
)
```

Am I missing something very obvious? It feels like I am but I can't quite see it. I've searched and haven't found this addressed specifically anywhere. Python/pandas would be ideal but R is ok too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dot product:

```
d.loc[:, d.columns.str.startswith('Q1')].T.dot(d.loc[:, d.columns.str.startswith('Q2')])
Out: 
     Q2a  Q2b  Q2c
Q1a    0    1    3
Q1b    3    4    6
Q1c    1    2    2
Q1d    2    3    3
```

The parts `d.loc[:, d.columns.str.startswith('Q1')]` and `d.loc[:, d.columns.str.startswith('Q2')]` basically selecting columns. It can be done more clearly with `d.filter(like='Q1')` as [@Zero suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381713/crosstabs-contingency-table-across-two-groups-of-variables/46381736?noredirect=1#comment79721871_46381736):

```
d.filter(like='Q1').T.dot(d.filter(like='Q2'))
```

If you want to select columns arbitrarily, you can just pass a list of column names instead. The equivalent of the above is

```
d.loc[:, ['Q1a', 'Q1b', 'Q1c', 'Q1d']].T.dot(d.loc[:, ['Q2a', 'Q2b', 'Q2c']])
```

Comment: Wow that was fast, thanks ayhan. Dot product, of course. Responses need converting if they're coded differently from 0/1 but that's easy. But what if I want to specify variables arbitrarily? For example rows=Q1a,Q1b and columns=Q1c,Q1d,Q27f,Q99e. I'm not sure how to change the syntax of your command to do that but assume it's possible?

Comment: Similarly, `d.filter(like='Q1').T.dot(d.filter(like='Q2'))` perhaps?

Comment: @Zero Thanks! That's much cleaner.

Comment: @GrahamJones I've updated the post with a list of column names to select. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @ayhan It works perfectly. I got to basically the same thing from Zero 's post as well: `d[['Q1a','Q1b','Q1c','Q1d']].T.dot(d[['Q2a','Q2b','Q2c']])`. Thanks to both of you, much appreciated.